# JNA - How to turn `char ***devices` PointerByReferences to `char **devices` PointerByReference

Tags: java, kotlin, pointers, jna

Here is the c header file:

```
idevice_error_t idevice_get_device_list(char ***devices, int *count);
idevice_error_t idevice_device_list_free(char **devices);
```

Here is the JNA that JNAerator generated for me:

```
int idevice_get_device_list(PointerByReference devices, IntBuffer count);
int idevice_device_list_free(PointerByReference devices);
```

Here is how I'm using it. It's in Kotlin, but it's equivalent to what you'd do in Java too:

```
fun getDeviceList(): List<String> {
    val deviceUuidsPbr = PointerByReference()
    val deviceSizeBuffer = IntBuffer.wrap(IntArray(1))
    
    val resultInt = LibIMobileDeviceLibrary.INSTANCE.idevice_get_device_list(deviceUuidsPbr, deviceSizeBuffer)

    val size = deviceSizeBuffer.get()
    logger.v {"getDeviceList $resultInt, Size: $size" }

    val stringArrayP = deviceUuidsPbr.value
    val devices = stringArrayP
        .getStringArray(0, size)
        .toList()

    logger.v { "Devices: $devices" }

    LibIMobileDeviceLibrary.INSTANCE.idevice_device_list_free(deviceUuidsPbr)

    return devices
}
```

Everything blows up when I free memory:

```
LibIMobileDeviceLibrary.INSTANCE.idevice_device_list_free(deviceUuidsPbr)
```

The free wants a `char **devices`, but I'm submitting a `char ***devices`. How should I get the `PointerByReference` into the correct format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `PointerByReference` is just a pointer (to a pointer).  And the two C functions being mapped simply have an extra level of indirection.

Consider this function definition:

```
device_get_device_list(char ***devices, int *count);
idevice_device_list_free(char **devices);
```

now consider `foo` defined to be `*devices` and the original functions simplify to:

```
device_get_device_list(char **foo, int *count);
idevice_device_list_free(char *foo);
```

And if you define `bar` as `*foo` you get:

```
device_get_device_list(char *bar, int *count);
idevice_device_list_free(char bar);
```

So you cannot pass the `PointerByReference` you are receiving from `device_get_device_list` (`*bar`) directly to `idevice_device_list_free` (which needs `bar`); you pass its pointed-to value (which happens to be a pointer to another pointer, but that doesn't matter.)

In Java you would simply change the argument in your `idevice_device_list_free()` call from `deviceUuidsPbr` to `deviceUuidsPbr.getValue()`.

I am not a Kotlin user but it would seem based on your other code that you need `deviceUuidsPbr.value` there.

Comment: Awesome :) Thanks for your clearly explained response. Seems to be working.